# В какой области памяти программы, написанной на C, хранятся строковые литералы во время ее исполнения?

Tags: c, указатели, литерал

Хочу понять, почему не могу объявить литерал в переменной, вот так:

```
char s = "some_text";
```

приходится делать это с помощью указателя:

```
char *s = "smth";
```

Может ли это быть связанно с тем, что такие литералы хранятся в стеке или куче?

Я знаю что литералы хранятся в смежных ячейках памяти (т.е., в соседних), а где хранятся эти смежные ячейки?

Comment: Это связано с тем, что `char` — это число от -128 до 127 (чаще всего), и пытаться запихнуть в него строковый литерал нет никакого смысла

Answer (score 3):

Это связано с тем, что в объявлении

```
char s = "some_text";
```

вы выделяете ровно 1 (прописью: *один*) байт для хранения всего текста. Что, очевидно, не работает...

```
char s = 's';
```

вполне работоспособно...

Answer (score 1):

Строки программы имеют тип массива букв `char [ ]` и они хранятся в коде программы, которая защищена от изменения.
Поэтому ваша запись

```
char *s = "smth";
```

создаёт переменную с типом указателя на первую букву константной строки и чтобы не было удивления от ошибок краха памяти надо объявлять её так :

```
char const * s = "smth" ;
s [ i ] - там буква с типом char const
```

или указателем на сам массив :

```
char const ( * p ) [ ] = ( char const ( * ) [ ] ) & "smth" ;
( * p ) [ i ] - там буква с типом char const
```

и чтобы была возможность изменять данную строку нужно создавать её копию так :

```
char s [ ] = "smth" ;
s [ 0 ] = 'S' ; - новую строку можно менять, заменяя буквы
```

или

```
char st [ 60 ] ;
strncpy ( st , "smth" , 59 ) ;
st [ 59 ] = '\00' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

строки хранятся на стеке, можно выделить память под строку через malloc, тогда она будет в куче (heap).
Вы же пихаете строку (массив) в один байт (char), что невозможно. Если же идёте через указатель, то размещаете один символ по адресу указателя.

Comment: Строковый литералы не хранятся на стеке. Указатели на них бывают на стеке, сами литералы - нет.